# How to search for the file path of a a process that shows up in TCP Connections more than 4 times

Tags: powershell, pid

I am trying to write a script that looks at what processes are making connections, and if it shows up more than 4 times, to write out the file path to the executable of that item.  Ideally, I would like to exclude things like Outlook, Chrome, SVC Host, etc.  So far, what I have is

```
$Processes=(Get-NetTCPConnection).owningProcess
$Array= @(
Foreach ($Process in $Processes | Where-Object ($_.Count -gt 4))
{
    Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path 
    }
)
$array
```

But this does not put out anything. If I remove the "Where-object clause" it puts out way more information than is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `Group-Object` for this.

```
$Processes = (Get-NetTCPConnection).OwningProcess | Group-Object |
    Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 4}
$Array = $Processes | Foreach-Object {
    Get-Process -Id $_.Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
}
$Array
```

**Explanation:**

[Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-6) groups on a property or value. The output is a collection of `GroupInfo` objects that have a `Name` property, which contains the grouped value. It contains a `Count` property, which counts the number of matching values. Piping that object into `Where-Object` allows for a condition based on the `Count` property (`$_.Count -gt 4`).

Each `Name` value in the `GroupInfo` collection corresponds to a process ID. You can pipe those process IDs into [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-6) using the `-Id` parameter. The output of `Get-Process` will be a `Process` object that contains a `Path` property. Depending on the process `Path`, may or may not be empty.

[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) with the `-ExpandProperty` will return the expanded property for each element of the piped in collection.

Comment: This did exactly what i needed, thank you.  I was stuck trying to adjust the second part, didn't think to filter before.